# Parse Query: Limit 1 object(status) per user(array)

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have a Parse query of statuses, right now it returns all the statuses the current user follows in the last 24 hours with new on top. As you can see I am using a `NSMutableArray` to get the following users, then query for their statuses.

I would like it to limit it to only 1 status per user, so when a user updates a status, it replaces the old one.

Also if I could randomized the order on refresh that would be cool.

```
-(void)getFollowingStatus {

 PFQuery *following = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Phriends"];
[following whereKey:@"followeds" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].username];
[following findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    NSMutableArray *followingUsers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (PFObject *followingActivities in objects) {
        PFUser *user = [followingActivities objectForKey:@"following"];
        [followingUsers addObject:user];}

    NSDate* CurrentTime = [NSDate date];

    NSDate *newDate = [CurrentTime dateByAddingTimeInterval:-86400];


    PFQuery *feed = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Pheed"];
    [feed whereKey:@"user" containedIn:followingUsers];
    [feed whereKey:@"createdAt" greaterThan:newDate];
    [feed orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

    [feed findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        //
        if (!error) {
            self.wallObjectsArray = objects;
            [self loadWallViews];
        } else {
             [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error userInfo][@"error"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        }
    }];
}];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot use the `limit` query parameter to limit the size of array attributes. I suggest doing something like this:

```
[feed findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSMutableArray * statuses = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (PFUser * user in objects)
            [statuses addObject:[user.statuses firstObject];
        self.wallObjectsArray = [statuses copy];
        [self loadWallViews];
    } else {
         [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error userInfo][@"error"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }
}];
```

Hopefully I understood your situation correctly. Basically, you need to construct a new array in which you only take the first status from each user.

Comment: Thanks, you did understand correctly, and yes limits would only work if I wanted the 'current_user' status only. Your query should work thx

Comment: I am having trouble tho, `firstObject` can only be called on certain things right?

Comment: correct, on an NSArray or NSMutableArray. I assumed your property was an array of statuses.

Comment: Ya just "username" and "comment" array from a table. How will `firstObject` return the most recent one for each `username`? - Maybe I should say that the `User` table only contains the user profile. -- I know we're trying to grab the first object per username.

Comment: Where are the statuses coming from? Parse has an Array datatype which stays in the order in which you add them. So the most recently added object would be last, while the oldest would be first.

Comment: First I check the "Phriends" table to see who the user follows, so rows of current_user, user. Then i check the "Pheed" table to pull every user and his comment rows in Descending order from the last day. So there must be a way to limit 1 recent comment-status for each user. I think I may have to rewrite to update instead of replace.

Answer (score 2):

You can limit the number of results by setting limit. By default, results are limited to 100, but anything from 1 to 1000 is a valid limit:

```
query.limit = 10; // limit to at most 10 results
```

If you want exactly one result, a more convenient alternative may be to use `getFirstObject` or `getFirstObjectInBackground` instead of using `findObject`.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
[query whereKey:@"playerEmail" equalTo:@"dstemkoski@example.com"];
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
  if (!object) {
    NSLog(@"The getFirstObject request failed.");
  } else {
    // The find succeeded.
    NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved the object.");
  }
}];
```

**Reference:** [Parse.com Query Documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS)

Comment: Thanks, I may use this to retrieve if a user follows someone and delete that relationship if it exists.